# How is the winner determined in case of server failure or disconnect?

Tags: hearthstone

I had always assumed that, if you were disconnected, you would receive a loss. However, I was watching a streamer tonight and the servers went down; upon returning, he had received a win on his arena game.

How is the winner determined in a game when both players simultaneously lose connection? Is this the same for arena/ranked/casual?

Comment: Probably something easy to deduce, like the amount of life left, but I'm only speculating.

Comment: That might be the simplest to calculate, but in Hearthstone having more life doesn't mean much.

Comment: I know that, but in situations like these I would think Blizzard doesn't want to get caught up in endless discussions about how to interpret the game state to decide who is most likely to win, so keep-it-simple would probably be somewhat of a good idea. In any case it was just speculation on my part.

Comment: it might even be a win for both, as if the servers go down, it is blizzard who lost.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a disconnect counts as a loss.  Maybe the opponent conceded for some reason?

Comment: I suspect the question is what happens if the server fails (or loses its connectivity), i.e. both users become disconnected simultaneously. Difficult to test, so probably hard to answer unless anybody can find word from Blizzard.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, either the opponent conceded or got disconnected first.

The win is handed to the player who was still connected when the other player was disconnected. Depending on geographic location and other technical details, there is some randomness involved when both players lose connection to the servers or the servers downright break down.

If both player actually do lose the connection at the same time (from the server's point of view), then the game is recorded as a draw.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the reward is given upon disconnection type, i explain:

If the disconnection is due to the HS server, the (or both) player will get a win regardless of the state of the game, as compensation for the technical malfunction (much like the "cancelled defeat" system in case of lag in the server of league of legends)

Otherwise, if the disconnection is due to one player internet service, then once he reconnects he will get a loose obviously,

Last case, when both players disconnected (their own internet service problem) wich is extremely rare, will both get a defeat once reconnected.

Source : HS Patch note i read, but i don't a find a link to